# What is a good execution time for a web page in php?

Tags: php, html

see the title :)

Comment: Whatever is acceptable to your users

Comment: That's a very vague question. What's the server hardware, what's the traffic on your site, how complex is the php script, and so on.

Comment: The answer to this question is impossible to determine without additional information.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think anyone can objectively answer this. It all depends on your clients and their needs. Obviously, if your page does heavy-duty work and your clients are aware of it, it can run for much longer than something they expect (or want) to be blazing fast, like search results.

Comment: I’d say five seconds, give or take. :-D (okokok, don’t hit me!)

Comment: You only decide what is best execution time by putting limit set_time_limit :)

Comment: You'll need to put in more context if you want a good answer. Do you have a page that *should* load fast but isn't? Do you have some algorithm with high complexity that you *know* will run slow, maybe it should run async? Tell us more!

Answer (score 4):

Whatever is reasonable for the content that gets displayed...

Comment: If you can't give a precise answer to a question, you should not answer it.

Comment: zneak, This answer is the correct one.  This question doesn't have a precise answer.

Comment: @zneak: This is the best answer you can give to this question ;) +1

Comment: @zneak: given the amount of detail in the question, I don't think it's possible to get more precise than this.

Comment: @Brad Don't forget the @ before my name if you want me to get notified. @nikic Good questions have good answers; bad questions have no good answer. "Witty" isn't the same as "good". While "witty" is fun, it's not what we're looking for. This answer helped no one. I wonder how you can say it's good.

Comment: @zneak, You clearly don't understand the question, nor the answer to it.  This entirely depends on many factors, and the right answer for a broad question is a broad answer.  Precisely the reason this question was closed by the moderators.  Ocelot20's answer was entirely appropriate.

Comment: @Brad Read carefully who voted to close this question. ;) Also, how can this answer be good if it helped no one? Clearly the question wasn't a good one and we both agree on that. However, I maintain that bad questions don't have good answers. If an answer helps no one, why give it better visibility? Why award reputation for it?

Comment: @zneak, I'm pretty sure xRobot was/will be helped by the answer.

Comment: @Brad I'm not. Don't you think he already knew that?

Comment: @zneak: Maybe now he knows that there is not "best" time...

Comment: @zneak, No actually. Working at a college (non-faculty, but often assisting students) questions come up all the time where students are looking for some magical absolute correct answer. "What is the maximum size in bytes an image for a mobile site can be?" "At what size network should I start to segment with VLANs?" The students simply aren't used to thinking about problems in the proper way. They are accustomed to a test-like structured environment, and real problems aren't like that. The answer gives the OP specific clues leading to the answer, and the correct way of thinking for the future.

Comment: @nikic, @Brad, I'm myself a student and I know how sometimes people expect that there are specific conventions for whatever. However, the same information (that there is no correct, unique answer) is conveyed through the comments and through the fact the question was closed. There are specific means to indicate a wrong trail of thought, and answers aren't one of them. I'm not against notifying that there isn't any real answer: I'm opposed to this information being an answer in itself, because of how reputation works.

Comment: @nikic, @Brad, I asked a question about it on meta so next time we'll know better what to think. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/69186/is-such-an-answer-appropriate-to-a-bad-question

Answer (score 4):

Totally, utterly subjective (thus, CW):

Anything between 0.0 and 0.4 seconds feels fine. Anything above it creates a notable delay.

On a public web site, when the average time to serve a page goes notably above 0.4 seconds, it is time to start thinking about caching.

Answer (score 1):

Not PHP-specific, but I've read that if a page takes more than 4 seconds to load it's too long.

Possible citation: [Akamai Technologies](http://www.akamai.com/html/about/press/releases/2006/press_110606.html) and it's also on [Vincent Flander's Web Redesign Checklist](http://www.webpagesthatsuck.com/does-my-web-site-suck/does-my-web-site-suck-checklist-part-one.html):

> Our home page — or any page — takes more than four seconds to load.

Comment: I agree. Obviously there's cases where a user requests a process that is known to take a long time, but in those cases the user usually *knows* it's a long-running job, and ideally, it's run as a separate aynchronous process on the server such that the user can query the status.